# possible to hide function property so it can not be seen outside the function?

Tags: javascript, static-variables

I'm writing a function to store canvas patterns. If a canvas pattern is requested and it exists, a reference to the canvas is returned, else the canvas is created first and then the reference is returned.

My first try was adding these canvas references to a separate global variable, but then I changed it to adding them to the function instead (as this saves a variable).

However, I'm able to read the property from anywhere in the code (without having to call the function). This is not really a big issue, but I wondered if it could be hidden (so, only a call allows acces to the property via return).

```
alert(myFunction("keyOne")); // "keyOne " + timestamp of now
alert(myFunction("keyTwo"));

alert(myFunction("keyOne")); // same as above, because there it was created
alert(myFunction("keyTwo"));

alert(myFunction.keyOne); // can read it without calling the function, is it possible to hide it?

function myFunction(myKey)
{
    if (!(myFunction.hasOwnProperty(myKey))) { myFunction[myKey] = myKey + " " + Date(); }
    return myFunction[myKey];
}
```

**edit: I don't know which answer to accept. Adding a variable is just the thing I'm trying to avoid. Also it adds a lot of fuss to the code that makes it hard to read (but it might be the only way to do it). If this is true, I'll leave it like this. Readability is very important to me.**

Answer (score 1):

You could capture the map of keys and values in a closure, instead of setting it as a static property on the function object:

```
var myFunction = (function () {

    var keys = {};

    return function (myKey) {
        if (!keys.hasOwnProperty(myKey)) {
            keys[myKey] = myKey + " " + Date();
        }
        return keys[myKey];
    };

}());
```

The function expression that appears to be assigned to `myFunction` is immediately invoked, so its return value is actually what gets assigned. Its return value happens to be another function, so `myFunction` now contains a reference to that inner, returned function.

Since that returned function contains references to the `keys` variable declared in the parent scope, that variable cannot be garbage-collected once the function containing it returns. You have created a closure which keeps the reference to `keys` available, even though `keys` itself is no longer accessible directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.

Simply create a immidiately invoked function expression for the purpose of a closure that will hold a reference to the object containing the data myFunction operates on.

```
var myFunction;
(function () {
    var inner = {};

    myFunction = function (myKey) {
        if (!(inner.hasOwnProperty(myKey))) { inner[myKey] = myKey + " " + Date(); }
        return inner[myKey];
    }
}());
```

Comment: That would reset `inner` every time `myFunction` is called, which would defeat the point.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide it inside an anonymous function:

```
(function(ns) {

    var store = {};

    ns.myFunction = function(myKey) {
        if (!store.hasOwnProperty(myKey)) {
            store[myKey] = myKey + ' ' + Date();
        }
        return store[myKey];
    }
}(this));
```

I implicitly pass `window` in the wrapper function as the "namespace" under which the function should be defined. The `store` variable can't be reached from outside.